# scraping all the data from attribute <a>

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the code I have written so far I need to get all the ids from the page.
[image]

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=all"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
ID = soup.find_all("a")
data =[]
for name in ID:
    data.append({"ID":name.text})
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
prind(pd)
```

Comment: Please, translate your whole question to an understandable way so we can know for sure what you want to achieve and what is the error, problem, issue you are facing at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=all"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
ID = soup.find_all("a")
data = [{"ID":name.text} name.text.isnumeric() for name in ID]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Tell me if its not working...